# Magnific Popup - Scroll using the Ajax popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I know the lightbox gallery you can scroll left and right and view picture after picture but is this possible with the ajax popup? I don't believe you can assign a delegate to allow this functionality.

Examples [here](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it's possible with ajax too, you can even mix ajax with another content type.

```
<button class="link">Click me</button>
<script>
$('.link').magnificPopup({
  items: [
    {
      src: 'ajax-file.html'
    },
    {
      src: 'ajax-file-2.html'
    },
    {
      src: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_b.jpg',
      type: 'image'
    }
  ],
  type: 'ajax',
  gallery: {
    enabled: true
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try in a bit. Is it possible to have all the links inline and have a delegate type variable? That way I just have all the links as such `<a class="popup" href="ajax-file.html">file</a><a class="popup" href="ajax-file-2.html">file</a>` and the delegate as `a.popup`